# Custom Control changing properties itself everytime I close Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Almost everytime I close VisualStudio my custom ToggleControl changes it's properties (size, location, margin) so it moves around in Designer, and gets bigger and bigger...

As I checked now location was set to 32000;32000, margin to 3;69000;3;69000 and size also some big number.

What could be the issue with this? I can't really find anything.

On another Tabcontrol I have the same ToggleControl that works fine, I tried to copy it but result is same.

Edit: Added control code

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Toggle
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    Private _checked As Boolean
    Public Property Checked As Boolean
        Get
            Return _checked
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If Not _checked.Equals(value) Then
                _checked = value
                Me.OnCheckedChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overridable Sub OnCheckedChanged()
        RaiseEvent CheckedChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Public Event CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseClick(e As MouseEventArgs)
        Me.Checked = Not Me.Checked
        Me.Invalidate()
        MyBase.OnMouseClick(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Me.OnPaintBackground(e)
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        Using path = New GraphicsPath()
            Dim d = Padding.All
            Dim r = Me.Height - 2 * d
            path.AddArc(d, d, r, r, 90, 180)
            path.AddArc(Me.Width - r - d, d, r, r, -90, 180)
            path.CloseFigure()
            e.Graphics.FillPath(If(Checked, Brushes.DarkGray, Brushes.LightGray), path)
            r = Height - 1
            Dim rect = If(Checked, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(Width - r - 1, 0, r, r), New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, r, r))
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(If(Checked, Brushes.Green, Brushes.LightSlateGray), rect)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

This code is from several sources over the years and has some minor tweaks. It appears it exist in various forms on different sites so it's unclear who to attribute.

Comment: *Custom Control* means you have custom code. Could you share a [MCVE] for your custom control?